# уравнение окружности

Tags: математика

Пишу программу, которая определит, лежит ли эта точка в области A, B или C.

Скажите, чему равно уравнение окружности (x^2 + y^2 = 1) в областях A, B, C? (Язык Java).

Как я понял, если поделить окружность пополам (левую и правую части), то левая часть равна x^2 + y^2 < 1, а правая часть равна x^2 + y^2 > 1.

Но на практике оказалось неверно.

**Вопрос: чему равно уравнение (x^2 + y^2 = 1) в областях A, B, C?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уравнение окружности это выражение, которое истинно для каждой точки, которая лежит на окружности и ложно для точек вне ее. Поэтому фраза `уравнение окружности для областей А, В, С` не имеет смысла. Объясните, что вы имеете ввиду, когда ее пишете.

Comment: @Roman Konoval, как понять что точка лежит в области A? x собственно <= 0, y>-x, а что еще нужно указать?

Comment: в таблице уже указаны все условия принадлежности к областям, что не так?

Comment: Прямо на картинке написаны условия. Для А условие `x<=0 && y>-x && x*x+y*y<1`.

Comment: @Roman Konoval, эту таблицу я и заполнил чтобы максимально подробно показать. Но в ней ошибка. Эта ошибка возникает только из-за того, что неправильно указал ур-ие окружности для областей: для А действительно x*x+y*y<1? Почему?

Comment: @Евгений зачем их превращать в одно условие? что у вас в строке с A в таблице?

Comment: @IR42 даже если не превращать, точка (0,5;0) должна лежать в окружности, т.е. программа должна вывести true. Но выводит false. Здесь вообще не важно в одно условие или нет

Comment: @IR42 x*x + y*y в области C получается будет верным: x*x + y*y < 1?

Comment: (0,5; 0) не лежит в области A

Comment: @IR42 а для области B - лежит. для B тогда нужно указать x*x + y*y > 1 или как?Почему тогда не робит

Comment: в B неправильно, должно быть везде `x*x+y*y<1` или `x*x+y*y<=1` если с границей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x*x+y*y<1` означает, что точка лежит внутри круга. Для В у вас ошибка, там задано условие `x*x+y*y>1` т.е. точки *снаружи* круга, поэтому не работает для x=0.5 y=0.